# Why aren't the texture images correctly rendering the correct colors in places?

Tags: rendering, texturing

Okay like my previous question, I am trying to export some 3D models from a game. However, for some reason the textures all seem to be applied correctly and the lighting is applied. But some parts aren't correctly colored, like two noses are correctly colored pink but the third is yellow instead of pink. Half of their bodies are yellow when they should be brown. And on one of them the top of their hair is brown instead of yellow.

I have provided a link below for the blend file. Any help that can be provided is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You didnt pack the images in the blend file

Comment: @Denis I have updated the blend file with the packed images.

Comment: It looks like the UV islands are not properly positioned on the texture

Comment: @Denis How do I fix those?

Comment: You could manually position UVs on the texture to match the color or paint the colors again.

Comment: @Denis Sorry I am very new to this. How do I get into that?

Comment: Are you planning to do with that model? It has bones, are you going to animate it?

Comment: @Denis No I am not going to animate it, I just need a still image of the model. It does however have animations in the game, but I don't know how to put them with the model in blender (and I don't know if that would fix the problem).

However, there is some other models I have that will need animated to get a proper image of them.

Comment: @Denis The animation files are saved as smd files and they are just skeletons. I am not sure if they are of any help with the rendering problem.

Comment: Try this [Blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2416/)

Comment: @Denis Thanks that is just what I needed. How did you do that though (I have a ton more that I have to do, but some are going to need some animation or something since they are in very weird poses)?

Comment: Instead of using a texture, just change color of the materials.

Comment: Okay thanks. I might have a couple more questions that I will post here, since there is some with patterns that are all weird.

Comment: Try bringing the "Specular" slider down to zero temporarily.   That's found under Material properties.  (tiny brown ball at top)

Comment: @Edgel3D Not sure what you mean by bringing the "Specular" slider down to zero, since under the Specular section there is only an intensity and hardness bar. I tried both of those, and neither appeared to change anything in the render.

Comment: Apologies, I should have used the proper term - intensity. It was a suggestion only because all too often the specular setting (intensity) can change how a material colour  (color) looks.